# How to unite and classify 2 dataframes based on several columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Hello I'm new in Pandas so I don't know what is the best option to use (or even if this is possible) I have the following 2 Dataframes (I receive them as parameter, so I'm not sure how they were really built):

```
___________|_mean_|_std_|_epoch_|
file1      |   0  |  4  |  300  | 
file2      |   2  |  1  |  300  |
file3      |   3  |  2  |  300  |

___________|_mean_|_std_|_epoch_|
file1      |   1  |  4  |  400  | 
file2      |   3  |  5  |  400  |
file3      |   3  |  6  |  400  |
```

While trying the Concat function I just get both dataframes united like this.

```
___________|_mean_|_std_|_epoch_|
file1      |   0  |  4  |  300  | 
file2      |   2  |  1  |  300  |
file3      |   3  |  2  |  300  |
file1      |   1  |  4  |  400  | 
file2      |   3  |  5  |  400  |
file3      |   3  |  6  |  400  |
```

and merge shows only the columns but no values...

And I'm looking for something like this:

```
______|_epoch_|_mean_|_std_|
file1 |  300  |   0  |  4  |
      |  400  |   1  |  4  |
file2 |  300  |   2  |  1  |
      |  400  |   3  |  5  |
file3 |  300  |   3  |  2  |
      |  400  |   3  |  6  |
```

Is there a way to do this type of dataFrame presentation?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for `.sort_index()`?

Comment: Hi @wjandrea I don't think that's is exactly what I'm looking for. It would be to merge the dataframes grouping them by file name and maybe later to sort index epoch based on each file

Comment: Did you try it? What you're showing here is not a merge, and `epoch` doesn't look like an index. But if it is, please provide a [reproducible pandas example](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: `pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_index()` is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you @QuangHoang  you were right. That's what I needed

Answer (score 0):

set the index of each dataframe and concat using axis=0?

```
data1 = {'fileName':['file1', 'file2', 'file3'], 'mean':[0,2,3], 'std':[4,1,2], 'epoch':[300,300,300]}
data2 = {'fileName':['file1', 'file2', 'file3'], 'mean':[1,3,3], 'std':[4,5,6], 'epoch':[400,400,400]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame().from_dict(data1).set_index('fileName')
df2 = pd.DataFrame().from_dict(data2).set_index('fileName')

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)

print(df)
          mean  std  epoch
fileName                  
file1        0    4    300
file2        2    1    300
file3        3    2    300
file1        1    4    400
file2        3    5    400
file3        3    6    400
```

then you can aggregate with groupby:

```
df.groupby(['fileName']).size()
fileName
file1    2
file2    2
file3    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: OP already tried concat, plus `axis=0` by default. What are you proposing exactly that's different?

Comment: You are right, my answer isn't too useful :(